# Robot Framework HTML format for several MESSAGE in report

Tags: html, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I would like to define the * HTML * format of the "message" field in the robotframework report

For example: If I have a 1st error message defined with the message field of the Keyword 'Page should contains element'
The 2nd message will be defined in 'Set Test Message'

Code example:

```
Page should contains element | locator | message=Error message1
```

Another Keyword

```
Set test message | * HTML * <b>Error message2</b> | append=True
```

In report message block i have :

```
Error message1 < b >Error message2< /b >
```

If i set `* HTML *` in message= `* HTML *Error message1` i can see `* HTML *` label in report

I would like define `${TEST MESSAGE}=* HTML * + ${TEST MESSAGE}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. need just to insert Set Test Message  | * HTML *${TEST MESSAGE} in teardown